# Inserting in inside a function

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I am a newbie at interacting with mongo and I am trying to make a function using the `in` property:

```
def find_inthe(key,*values):
    rdo=col.find({key:{'$in':list(values)}})
    for a in rdo:
        return a

print(find_inthe('hair_colour','white','brown','black'))
```

However the problem I am finding is that it is returning only the first of the `values` and as a `find_one`.

If I try the same outside the function:

```
rdo=col.find({'hair_colour':{'$in':['white','brown','black']}})          
for a in rdo:
    print(a)
```

It will return all the dictionaries of the collection.

My desired output would be that the function returns all the dictionaries with the selected colour hairs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$in` is not at fault here. It's your `return a` in the loop. Why don't you return the whole thing?

```
def find_inthe(key,*values):
    rdo = col.find({key:{'$in':list(values)}})
    return list(rdo)
```

Comment: That would output `pymongo.cursor.Cursor object at....` 
it would work in case I used `find_one`.
When using find by itself requires the `for`

Comment: @ge00rge: make it a list then

Comment: @ge00rge: no, it doesn't require `for`, that'd be silly.

Comment: You are right , sorry about that Im an absolute noob